# Agile Web Development on Rails. 10.4 -undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am stuck here and it seems that there is no answer anywhere online. The exercise says:

Create a migration that copies the product price into the line item, and change the add_product method in the Cart model to capture the price whenever a new line item is created.

My code:

```
class AddPriceToLineItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :line_items, :price, :decimal
    say_with_time "Updating prices..." do
    LineItem.find(:all).each do |li|
      li.update_attribute :price, li.product.price
    end
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :line_items, :price
  end
end
```

I also tried:

```
class AddPriceToLineItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :line_items, :price, :decimal
    LineItem.all.each do |li|
      li.price = li.product.price
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :line_items, :price
  end
end
```

I keep getting this error:

```
 rake db:migrate
==  AddPriceToLineItem: migrating =============================================
-- add_column(:line_items, :price, :decimal)
   -> 0.0010s
-- Updating prices...
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass
```

It is weird that it is saying undefined nil:nilClass, as price has just been defined in the line before.

Im using rails (3.2.1), ruby 1.9.3p125.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

This errors means that you are calling `price` on something that is `nil`. So I'm pretty sure one of your `LineItem` does not have a `product`.

Comment: Thank you! I added:
li.price = li.product.price if li.price
And it worked!  I have no idea, why I have one list item without a product though...

Answer (score 0):

I would be more particular. In my case a had a cart_id and product_id were nil.

So I simple clean up the DB by

```
sqlite> DELETE FROM line_items WHERE id= bad_id";
```